# Using exchange server 2007 web service

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using the exchange server 2007 web service in order to create tasks using C#.
Can i create tasks and assign it to some other user in exchange server.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209030/creating-tasks-for-other-users-using-exchange-web-services-ews-managed-api