# Creating read-only exchange tasks for a user

Tags: exchange-server, task, readonly, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I want to use the Exchange Web Services in a service (more specifically in a sharepoint activity) in order to assign a task to someone else.
That was already answered  [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209030/creating-tasks-for-other-users-using-exchange-web-services-ews-managed-api)
However, I also want that task to be readonly, so the user cannot modify it, but only the service user (as I want to keep the tasks information in sync with sharepoint data)

Can I achieve this using EWS? and if "yes", are there any how-tos plase? :)

And: SharePoint Tasks are no matter for me. We use our own specialized content types --> therefore we cannot use SharePoint tasks for Exchange sync.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible. The user of a mailbox is the owner of all items. You cannot take his permissions away from him.

That being said, there is one workaround: When a user modifies one of your special tasks, just restore the original values.

You can either periodically check the tasks for changes or use push/pull notifications (in case of Exchange 2010, there are also streaming notifications available).