# Creating Task Request using EWS and MAPI

Tags: exchangewebservices, mapi

I am facing the problem of creating task request via EWS. However, still failing. The best I could create was messege which contains task as attachment. This message contains Accept and Decline button but the buttons are not clickable. Is there anything else what I need to set e.g. some MAPI properties?

I know that there is no way to create standartly in EWS but Outlook must do it some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, assigning Tasks to other people is not possible using EWS (see for [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/2d1d88dc-9b79-4c0c-b438-cc04ff60286f/ews-tasks-no-assignees?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment&forum=exchangesvrdevelopment). This question is rather old, though).

A similar question which might be useful was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209030/creating-tasks-for-other-users-using-exchange-web-services-ews-managed-api).

Outlook uses another interface than EWS, so they can't be compared. A better comparison is typically OWA, which also does not support assigning tasks.